# Axon - Does the unique Id of my Aggregate equal/be the same as that of my Entity?

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, axon

I must be doing something wrong here.

I have a very simple Axon application that has two simple functions: ***create a person & change the name of the person***.

So I have Person Entity:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Person {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

And my PersonAggregate:

```
@Aggregate
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class PersonAggregate {

    @AggregateIdentifier
    private UUID id;
    private String name;


    @CommandHandler
    public PersonAggregate(CreatePersonCommand command) {
        apply(new PersonCreatedEvent(
                command.getId(),
                command.getName()
        ));
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(PersonCreatedEvent event) {
        this.id = event.getId();
        this.name = event.getName();
    }

    @CommandHandler
    public void handle(ChangeNameCommand command) {
        apply(
                new NameChangedEvent(
                        command.getId(),
                        command.getName()
                )
        );
    }

    @EventSourcingHandler
    public void on(NameChangedEvent event) {
        this.name = event.getName();
    }

}
```

And this is my ChangeNameCommand:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ChangeNameCommand {
    @TargetAggregateIdentifier
     private UUID id;
     private String name;    
}
```

And this is my NameChangedEvent:

```
@Value
public class NameChangedEvent {
    private final UUID id;
    private final String name;
}
```

And Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface PersonCommandRepository extends JpaRepository<Person, Long> {
}
```

The **Problem** is that I am not sure how to structure my Event Handler

```
@EventHandler
public void changeName(NameChangedEvent event) {
    Optional<Person> opt = null;//this.personCommandRepository.findById(event.getId());
    if (opt.isPresent()) {
        Person person = opt.get();
        person.setName(event.getName());
        this.personCommandRepository.save(person); //Does'nt this defeat the purpose of Event Sourcing? A single point of truth?
    }
```

And also, in my controller, I have quite I big problem, in the comment:

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/rename", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> changeName(@RequestParam("id") Long id, @RequestParam("name")String name){
        //1. Which Id do we pass in here? Aggregate or Entity?
        //this.commandGateway.send(new ChangeNameCommand(id,name));
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Renamed", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 repreentations o the same? Your aggregate is the person not some additional JPA entity.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mean my Aggregate must be my Entity? Like my Repository would be like `PersonCommandRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonAggregate, Long>`?

Comment: No. The aggregate is the `Person`. That is your source of thuth. You don't need the entity (which is already glaring in there judging by your own comment/question).

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, so how would my Repository look like? I am not sure, you may assist by modifying the code and post as an answer.

Comment: you don't need a repository, nor a jpa entity. As stated your aggregate IS the person you want. You can use the axon repositories to query it again.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, I heard you. But I am still starting Axon, so I am not sure how to implement your suggestions. Please, i you may assist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209917/discussion-between-nation-chirara-and-m-deinum).

Comment: You don't need to implement anything it is already there.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, but how would my Rest controller look like?

Comment: For what? It handles a request, creates a command and sends that to axon. For a query it does the same but for the query part and maybe on a projection of your entity. All that is explained in the axon manual and samplkes/tutorials. I strongly suggest you follow those instead of trying to figure things out yourself.

Comment: @M.Deinum Okay, I am getting the idea. Let me try it, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel you are still mixing the idea of the Command Model and the Query Model with one another.

The command model, which typically is the aggregate (or several), only handles **requests of intent to change some state**. These requests of intent, i.e. command message, are thus the sole operations targeted towards your aggregate/command model. Vice versa, if you have the requirement to change something on a Person, that means you dispatch a command marking that intent towards the `PersonAggregate`.

The query model on the other hand is solely tasked with answering the questions targeted towards your application. If there is somehow a need to know the state of a Person, that means you dispatch a query towards a component capable of returning the `Person` entity you have shared.

Going back to "the problems" you described:

1. *"Doesn't this defeat the purpose of Event Sourcing? A single point of truth?"*: Event Sourcing is a concept specific towards rehydrating the **command model** from the events **itself** has published. Thus, employing Event Sourcing just means you are making certain not only your query models are created through events, but also your command models. Ergo, you are enforcing a single source of truth by doing this. Using the events to update query models thus *does not* defeat the purpose of ES.
2. *"Which Id do we pass in here? Aggregate or Entity?"*: When you are in doubt, try to figure out what you want to achieve. Are you requesting information? Then it's a query targeted towards your query model. Is the intent to change some state to a model? Then you dispatch a command towards the command model. In this exact scenario, you want to change the name of a Person. Hence, you dispatch a command towards the Aggregate/Command Model.

On AxonIQ's webpage there is an [Architectural Concepts](https://axoniq.io/resources/architectural-concepts) section describing all the main principles. There's also one about [CQRS](https://axoniq.io/resources/cqrs) which might help.
Might help to read up on these; pretty sure a lot of these will solve a lot of the question you have. :-)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, Steven, yes I have been mixing things! I just finished watching your talk you gave in 2017, Kyiv & I am opening my email and seeing your response.  Yes, the "views - SpeakerView and ConferenceView" got me in the right direction! Let me check out the linked material, definitely it will help!

Comment: Very happy to hear this, but also my recording at Kyiv, has helped you out to have it all make sense! :-)